# Unordered List in CSS will not center

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, center

https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/5shg6vn7/3/

So I've been trying to get this Unordered List centered. The text-align:center; worked correctly but the items within the list (the pictures and text) for the main content of the page. I just want it to be perfectly centered. I've tried getting rid of padding and margins. I've tried margin: 0px auto;. I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to get this UL to align.

```
.mainImage{

   height:275px;
   width:275px;
}
.mainImageUl ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;

}
.mainImageUl li{

  padding:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  height:350px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Is using flexbox an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User agent styles adds a `padding-inline-start: 40px` to `ul` elements.

I see you have this in your css which should get rid of the padding but you are selecting the class `.mainImageUL` and a nesting `ul` element

```
.mainImageUl ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;

}
```

change it to this

```
.mainImageUl{
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0px auto;
   padding:0px;
}
```

This will target the correct element and correct your alignment issue

Answer (score 1):

`.mainImage` remains the same

```
.mainImage{
  height:275px;
  width:275px;
}
```

in `.mainImageUl ul` would change to `.mainImageUl`

```
.mainImageUl {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
}
```

`.mainImageUl li` you should use margin only if you only want to achieve a space between each image

```
.mainImageUl li{
          margin: 30px 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear browser css setting before adding yours
also it is better to share complete style sheet we should know if there is conflict or inheritance